# check connections to server

Tags: networking

Running a LAMP server in my RPI for my LAN. i have a few devices in my network for testing that each one calls a specific php file. eg device 1 calls file1.php, device 2 calls file2.php and so on. 
From the 10 devices overall i have 2 of them refusing to send data to RPI's LAMP server. I would like to see from the RPI's side if there is a try to connect and send or not. 
I did try to issue `netstat -a` but that gave me only the established connections currently active. I would like to know the attempts. Is there any way to find out please?

Comment: " 2 of them refusing to send data" is not sufficient information to understand your setup. What devices are they? Are they the same as the ones that work? Are you WiFi? What protocol are they using?

Comment: Do you tried to use a packet sniffer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a packet sniffer like *tcpdump* or *wireshark*. I prefer *tcpdump* for the command line. I would first capture the data stream from a device that connects successful to get an idea how it looks and what handshake there is. Then I would filter on the traffic to/from the device that does not work. You may see what fails.